# could do anything

Tags: modal-verbs

a. When he was drunk, he was unpredictable. He **could** do anything.

b. When he was drunk, he was unpredictable. He **might** do anything.

I am pretty sure (b) works, but how about (a). Can one use 'could' to express possibility in such a context, or could it only be used to express 'ability'?

Here the idea is that it was possible that he might do anything, not that he was capable to do anything.

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, _could_ can be used in this context (it was possible for him to do anything).

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfectly acceptable and have the same meaning: that when he was drunk, nobody could tell what he was going to do, and anything could happen.

> When he was drunk, he was unpredictable. He could do anything.

> When he was drunk, he was unpredictable. He might do anything.

You are also correct that **could** can also be used to express ability.

But it gets tricky because there's not really a hard line separating the two meanings. For example, I would consider this to be more about ability:

> When he was drunk, he thought he could do anything.

And this to be more about unpredictability:

> When he was drunk, he was unpredictable. He was capable of anything.

But at first glance, they might seem to be the opposite.

Comment: I think 'could' refers to the capability (ie through lack of inhibition), 'might' refers to the possibility of the thing actually happening.  In practice it makes little difference.